# How to scan only a part of a application in Webinspect

Tags: security

Can anyone explain the way to scan only a certain part of a web application using Webinspect?

Answer (score 0):

Actually John did not give you the link to the exact article.  Here it is:
"How to use Webinspect to scan only a part of a web application"
http://webappsecure.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-use-webinspect-to-scan-only-part.html

BTW - You should probably use the HP WebInspect user forum for further questions.  The developers and users are more attuned to this topic.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-Application-Security-Center/ct-p/sws-sc01

```
 Parent:  http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Application-Security/ct-p/sws-AS
```